# Is the phrase "have enabled to" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

I came across the following expression in a paper:

> Here, we have enabled to express X in terms of Y.

Is the above expression correct? It seems to me more correct to say, "... we have been enabled to express ...", but I am not sure.

Comment: *Enable* is a transitive verb, so using *enable* without any object would sound odd. (It's normally *enable someone to do something*.) I agree that *We have been enabled ...* sounds better. I also believe that *We are able to ...* or *We can ...* would sound even better.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Prolly just a dropped 'been', as OP suggests; but I wholeheartedly endorse your concise alternatives.

Comment: Perhaps **1st draft:** "we have enabled x to be expressed in terms of y" (which is too passive so then) **2nd draft:** "we have enabled to express x in terms of y".  Woops!  **Final Best Draft:** = "We are now able to express x in terms of y". Or **@DamkerngT.'s better-than-best:** "We can now express x in terms of y".

Comment: Perhaps the underlying sense is "We have made it possible to express..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although OP doesn't tell us *exactly* what he actually wants to say, I'm sure *enabled* isn't the right word. Perhaps the nearest "credible" version would be...

> *Here, we have **been able to** express X in terms of Y.*

But it's worth pointing out that unless there's some special reason for emphasising the "ability" involved (perhaps because we used an unusual method, without which it wouldn't have been *possible* to express X in terms of Y), it would be more natural to simply say...

> *Here, we have expressed X in terms of Y.*
>    or
>    *Here, we can express X in terms of Y.*